# pytorch faster r-cnn, no bounding box image return value error(all bounding boxes should have positive height and width)

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, vision, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to train Faster R-CNN on custom dataset.
When I train with no object image(image without bounding boxes), it returns value error 'All bounding boxes should have positive height and width'.

My dataset contains image, target([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], label).
For non-object image, target is ([0, 0, 0, 0], 0).

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I'm following this code.
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

and which one is correct method for training non-object images?

1. use [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] for non-object image
2. use [0, 0, w, h, 0] for non-object image(w, h is size of original image)

Comment: Same problem on my side. Currently the only workaround I see is to give the bounding box a width and height of 1 pixel. However this would still influence training somehow.

Comment: I tried [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5] too. But, it returns 0 loss